# OpenVPN: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, openvpn

I'm trying to install OpenVpnServer on Lubuntu 20.04. I'm not so expert with Linux, so I make many errors. At last I had an "almost working" OpenVpnServer installation, this is (hope so) the last error, but I've no idea on how to solve it. Hope that someone could help.
I get this error:
*systemd-udevd[129294]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable*
This is the log result:

```
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2306.
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2019
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to server.
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 NetworkManager[774]: <info>  [1589982167.8120] manager: (tun1): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/46)
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd-udevd[129294]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET]192.168.178.42:1194: Address already in use (errno=98)
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Exiting due to fatal error
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 10.8.0.1/24
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: `May 20 15:42:47 salvo-Latitude-E5500 ovpn-server[129293]: TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET]192.168.178.42:1194: Address already in use (errno=98)` - fix your binding, thats the issue ,)